# EXPO - Push notifications not working in production with iOS (Certificates 0)

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, expo

Everything works in development through the expo app, but after I publish notifications don’t reach the main app. I’m testing on iOS. I’m sending the push notifications from the backend using the expo module. What’s weird is even with both the ‘inside expo’ version and the stand alone app in the store, when they point at the same back end for some reason the notifications only show of for the one running from inside the expo app and not my stand alone production app.

Some have solved the problem with “expo build:ios --clear-credentials”, I have deleted and regenerated them, but it doesn’t work.

I have always done these operations by selecting “Let Expo handle the process”.

On the developer portal everything looks ok, but going up “https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list”, and check my app identifier, scroll at “push notification” I can see: “configure certificates (0)”.

I think there must be a certificate here to work, is it normal that expo didn’t do it automatically?

Do I have to do it manually?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rVDn.png)

Comment: How had you done for development? Are you using any .pem or .p12 or .p8 certificates for sending notification in development mode?

Comment: I don't know because following the official guide (https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/)  expo manages automatically the whole procedure

Comment: There should be a way where you can change from development to production. You have to switch to production mode.

Comment: Switch to Dev to Prod in EXPO side? or in apple dashboard?